# Array size deduction

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates, stl

Following an example from Scott Meyer's "Modern C++", I'd exploit `std::array` size deduction with templates. I'm stumbled trying to compile my `myUsage` function usage.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t arraySize(T (&) [N]) noexcept
{
        return N;
}

void scottUsage()
{
        int b[5];
        std::array<short, arraySize(b)> c;
        std::cout << arraySize(b) << " = " << c.size() << "\n";
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void myUsage(T & arr [N])
{
        for (auto i=0; i<arraySize(arr); i++)
                std::cout << arr[i] << "\t";
}

int main()
{
        scottUsage();

        int a[7];
        myUsage(a);
}
```

So two questions arise:

1. (*side question*) What's `(&)` for? Removing would trigger `error: creating array of references`, which it seems to be forbidden
2. What's wrong with `myUsage` signature?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `myUsage(T (&arr) [N])`? The parentheses are important to make it a reference to an array (instead of an array of references).

Comment: For sure, thank you both. Please provide comments as answers (maybe with few explanation of `(&varname)` uncommon syntax, and I'll be glad to mark as solved

Comment: Also, `a` in `main()` is an array of uninitialised `int`.  Printing the elements in `myUsage()`  - once you fix the typo with the argument - therefore causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Really Peter? I thought I was just reading garbage data. Anyway that was for example sake

Comment: @PatrizioBertoni It's best to keep examples as simple as possible so that you  don't accidentally introduce bugs that were originally not relevant to your question. In other words, examples should be *minimal*. see [mcve].

Comment: Reading (or, in your code here, printing) garbage data is a common symptom of accessing the value of an uninitialised variable (which does have undefined behaviour) - as your code does here.    There are many other possible symptoms of undefined behaviour though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myUsage()` needs to use `T (&arr) [N]`.

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void myUsage(T (&arr) [N])
```

The parentheses tell the compiler that the reference applies to the array itself and not to the element type of the array.

Also, both `arraySize()` and `myUsage()` should take a reference to `const` data:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t arraySize(const T (&) [N]) noexcept
...
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void myUsage(const T (&arr) [N])
```

BTW, `arraySize()` is not needed from C++17 onward, use [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) instead:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

void scottUsage()
{
    int b[5];
    std::array<short, std::size(b)> c;
    std::cout << std::size(b) << " = " << c.size() << "\n";
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void myUsage(const T (&arr) [N])
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < std::size(arr); ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    /* better:
    for (const T &value : arr)
        std::cout << value << "\t";
    */
}

int main()
{
    scottUsage();
    int a[7];
    myUsage(a);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> 1. What's (&) for?

It makes the argument a reference. If it wasn't a reference, then it would be an array. But function arguments are not allowed to be arrays, and such declarations are adjusted to be a pointer to an element of the array. Since this type does not carry information about size of the array, it is not useful to the size deduction.

> Removing would trigger error: creating array of references, which it seems to be forbidden
>
> ```
> void myUsage(T & arr [N])
> ```

Indeed, the parentheses are mandatory. They are needed to signify that the reference applies to the array and not the element type of the array. `T&[N]` is an array of references (which is not allowed) while `T(&)[N]` is a reference to an array.

> 2. What's wrong with myUsage signature?

Arrays of references are not allowed.